# How do I find the cpu the current thread is running on, for Mac and BSD?

Tags: multithreading, macos, bsd, cpuid, multiprocessor

I'm looking for a function on Mac OS and BSD that's equivalent to Linux's `sched_getcpu()`, and Windows' `GetCurrentProcessorNumberEx()` in order to implement a library for cpu-local storage. It's clearly possible to emulate this with the cpuid or rdtscp instructions, but it's possible to do better with kernel cooperation: https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/1/6/190.

I already know that the thread's current CPU may change by the time I use the information.

Answer (score 2):

There are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942686/how-to-know-where-queue-am-i-main-queue-or-not) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336322/how-to-get-hold-of-the-currently-executing-nsoperation) questions which cover queue tracking for OSX, as well as a [dispatch_get_global_queue](http://wiki.freebsd.org/GCD)  wiki page which covers the equivalent for BSD. I don't know if you can map a queue to a CPU, but if so, that would seem to be the closest equivalent.